# How to check if an array has 2 or 3 columns?

Tags: python, numpy

How to check if a given array as 2 or 3 columns? and how to set the 3rd column values to zero, after finding?

I am trying to debug the program,i know how to find the shape of an array but lets suppose this is the array.

```
array([[   0., -300.,   25.],
       [  25.,    2.,   25.],
       [  50.,    6.,   25.],
       [  75.,    2.,   25.],
       [  85.,    2.,   25.],
       [  30.,    2.,   25.],
       [  10.,    4.,   23.]])
```

thanks alot.

Comment: `data[:, 2] = 0` ?

Comment: `if... else` sentence?

Comment: OK Thanks. that's the second question, how to check if the array has 2 or 3 inputs or columns?

Comment: But you said you know how to find a shape. Do you know what `shape[0]` and `shape[1]` are for? You've got an answer btw.

Comment: If you break down your 2 problems, you will find a solution quickly on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = np.array([[   0., -300.,   25.],
       [  25.,    2.,   25.],
       [  50.,    6.,   25.],
       [  75.,    2.,   25.],
       [  85.,    2.,   25.],
       [  30.,    2.,   25.],
       [  10.,    4.,   23.]])

if arr.shape[1] == 3:
    arr[:, 2] = 0
```